# how to split an array homogene in half of size by taking the triagle?

Tags: python, arrays

**i have this array and i want to split it in the half how i can do it?**

```py
a = [[0., 15., 19., 18., 17.],
     [15., 0., 14., 12., 23.],
     [19., 14.,  0., 14., 21.],
     [18., 12., 14., 0., 14.],
     [17., 23., 21., 14.,  0.]]
```

**how i can get this half size of this array:**

```py
[[0.],
    [15.,0],
    [19., 14.,0],
    [18., 12., 14.,0],
    [17., 23., 21., 14.,0]]
```

Comment: The output is not a "standard" numpy array

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. why did you not show your own attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: i tried this for i in range(len(a)):
          print(a[:][:i+1])
and it show [[0.0, 15.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0]]
[[0.0, 15.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0], [15.0, 0.0, 14.0, 12.0, 23.0]]
[[0.0, 15.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0], [15.0, 0.0, 14.0, 12.0, 23.0], [19.0, 14.0, 0.0, 14.0, 21.0]]
[[0.0, 15.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0], [15.0, 0.0, 14.0, 12.0, 23.0], [19.0, 14.0, 0.0, 14.0, 21.0], [18.0, 12.0, 14.0, 0.0, 14.0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
half = [row[:i+1] for i, row in enumerate(a)]
```

If you do not want the diagonal, you can add `[1:]` :

```
half = [row[:i+1] for i, row in enumerate(a[1:])]
```

Comment: Why do you want to use enumerate?

Comment: It is so you don't have to call a[i], and can just write row.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your requirement you want to select

- `0` items from the `0` index.
- `1` item from the `1` index.
- `2` items from the `2` index.
  and so on...
  So simply do this:

```
res = [a[i][:i+1] for i in range(len(a))]
print(res)
```

What did I do above?

- Iterate over `a` and slice the values.
- Index + 1 since you want to include the index